# Reset Without Clearing syncErrors

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation, redux-form

I am working on a React-Native app that uses React-Navigation where I need to clear a redux-form when it's navigated away from, so the form is like new when navigated back to.

With React-Navigation, the component does not unmount so the form is not destroyed and created again when navigating back to it.

I am using `this.props.reset('formname')` which clears the form when navigating away, however this removes all of my validations stored in `syncErrors`.  When I return to the screen and click the submit button, it does not produce any validation errors due to `syncErrors` not being kept.

What is the proper way to reset a redux-form and return it like new without clearing `syncErrors` (keeping validations)?

Comment: it depends on how you are mounting and unmounting your form component. when you are navigating away from it, you should completely removed it from dome ( not just hide it)

Comment: Unfortunately with react-navigation for react-native it hides it and does not remove it.  In order to remove it I would have to reset the Stack Navigation in react-navigation and that causes other issues (I lose the transition animation for example).